# Ads not showing on Corona Project

Tags: ads, coronasdk

I have latest version of Corona SDK i.e. Version 2013.1135 (2013.6.3)
But except RevMob, I am not able to get any kind of Ads.
Every time when I include "ads" then it shows following warnings

WARNING: The 'ads' provider (**) is not available on the simulator
WARNING: The 'ads' library is not available on this platform.

** It could be iads or inmobi

In both case I am getting same warning.
Any Help?

Answer (score 2):

you must deploy your application on real devices because the simulator does not support advertisment just like the webview for corona

Comment: @Hamza Hasan: what DevfaR said is correct. So you have to either build your app for device or Xcode simulator for testing Ads.

Comment: Hey, I cannot perform proper build when I include ads library :( (with DeveloperTestProfile), it always return 'null' at the end of performing build. Yes it is ok when I exclude all the ads stuff. :(

Comment: Even with proper running app bundle id and proper respective provisioning developer profile :(

Comment: Although I am using free version of Corona SDK

Comment: RevMob is OK
perhaps due to separate class available for RevMob
but incase of any other ads (i have tried iads and inmobi), it is happening

Comment: oh i haven't use revmob for my advertisement

Comment: OK, but what about other ads? What possible reasons you recognized for not appearing other ads?

Comment: this is the possible problem: 
*wrong key or ID
*improper initialization
*ads won't load
*no internet connection
and there are ads that only work on specific localization of phone

Comment: Is the emulator still not able to show ads (Oct 2016)? Is there a way to sort of automate the process form an IDE (LuaGlider2) or from command line that would be quicker than making a build and copying the APK to an Android?